# Converting SMILES string into valid sub-strings

Tags: molecular-structure, cheminformatics

I have a SMILES string as follows.

```
smi= 'CCOC(=O)C1=C(COCCN)NC(C)=C(C(=O)OC)C1c1ccccc1Cl'
```

Is there anyway that I convert this SMILES string into valid sub-strings which can be later processed in RDKIT.

For instance

```
smi_sub1= 'C1c1ccccc1Cl'
smi_sub2= 'CCOC(=O)C1=C(COCCN)NC(C)=C(C(=O)OC)'
smi_sub3= 'C1=C(COCCN)NC(C)=C(C(=O)OC)'
```

These sub-strings should be subset of the main SMILES string and should also be valid from the **SMILES syntax** point of view.

So that when I use the function `MolFromSmiles`, It get processed without any error or none in return?

```
Mol_sub1 = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi_sub1)
Mol_sub2 = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi_sub2)
Mol_sub3 = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi_sub3)
```

Comment: Note that neither openbabel (version 3.1.0) accessed via its gui, nor the NIH pubchem sketcher (https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/edit3/index.html) are capable to process your smi_sub1, smi_sub2, or smi_sub3; which may indicate an error in your processing.  While lacking clarity topically, your question may be _interpreted_ like a scaffold identification.  The Murcko scaffold (e.g., https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.Scaffolds.MurckoScaffold.html) is one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this might work in some cases, I am not sure how well it will work in general. The problem here might be reflected in this statement:

> These sub-strings should be subset of the main SMILES string

Not every *substring* will be a *subgraph* of the parent molecule. As mentioned in the comments, this seems essentially a fragmentation problem. Take this one of your examples:

> smi_sub1= 'C1c1ccccc1Cl'

The reason this won't parse is that it starts with a 'C1' but has no corresponding 'C1' to finish the ring. So it should be 'Cc1ccccc1Cl', which is 1-chloro-2-methylbenzene.

Theoretically, you could take substrings, then post-process them to remove 'disconnected' ring numbers. However, it would make more sense to use proper fragmentation on the molecular graph, and then you would have correct subgraphs anyway, without the need to convert them from SMILES.

Comment: On a second thought, Daylight's SMILES tutorial (https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml_tutorials/languages/smiles/index.html) illustrates the theory (https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smiles.html) behind the conventions used.  Equally note the related SMARTS useful for sub-structure searches (https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smarts.html).